# Is it ok writing $\displaystyle L^2(\mathbb T^n)=\bigoplus_{j\in\mathbb N} E_{\xi_j}$?

Tags: functional-analysis

The family $(e_\xi)_{\xi\in\mathbb Z^n}\subset C^\infty(\mathbb T^n)$ defined by $e_\xi(x):=e^{2\pi ix\cdot \xi}$ is an orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb T^n)$ with respect to the inner product $$\langle f, g\rangle:=\int_{\mathbb T^n} f(x)\overline{g(x)}\ dx.$$  Is it ok writing $\displaystyle L^2(\mathbb T^n)=\bigoplus_{j\in\mathbb N} E_{\xi_j}$ where $E_{\xi_j}=\langle e_\xi: |\xi|= j\rangle_{\mathbb C}$ (linear span)?

Thanks

Comment: It seems like you've got redundancies there, unless you change the $\leq$ to =, but maybe I'm reading it wrong.   Also I think you need a little hat over the $\oplus$ to denote Hilbert space direct sum, I.e. the closure of the direct sum.

Comment: Sure, it must be $=$..